# How to associate an AngularJS controller with a route via a function's return value?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create an AngularJS slideshow app where users can add content within a `projects/` directory.

The router already uses variable routes.

```
.when('/:project', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        return 'projects/' + params.project + '/project.html';
    }
})
```

However, I can't figure out how to use variable Controller names.  For example, the following does not work:

```
.when('/:project', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        return 'projects/' + params.project + '/project.html';
    },
    controller: function() { return 'SomeController'; }
})
```

But this does:

```
.when('/:project', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        return 'projects/' + params.project + '/project.html';
    },
    controller: 'SomeController'
})
```

Is it possible to associate a controller with a route using a function?

If this sounds like a silly idea, let me explain what I'm trying to do.  Instead of having user's edit the `MainController`, I'd like to be able to write JavaScript specific to a project.  If a project gets deleted, that project's specific JavaScript is also deleted.  If a new project gets added that needs custom JavaScript, users can use an API (AngularJS Events) to interact with the UI.

What's the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI Router has [`controllerProvider` feature](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state). ngRoute doesn't have it.

The function specified in route `controller` is actual controller constructor, it can't just return controller name. It is [`ngView` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.3/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L258) that defines how route controllers are instantiated. Without patching the directive the behaviour can be simulated with:

```
controller: function ($scope, $controller) {
  return $controller('SomeController', { $scope: $scope });
}
```